# Architectural questions: solutions sharing same class libraries; project promotion; forking solutions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, architecture

I badly need to understand how to manage some very basic architectural issues in c# using Visual Studio 2010 and I have some trouble in finding  solutions in textbooks and web sites. Let's say I have a MyWinForm.sln solution which is based on: MyWinForm.cs and two class libraries, let's say: a.dll, b.dll My aim: I want to refactor the application I have coded just to learn C# in order to have a decent application architecture.

1. I wish to design a c.dll that must contain general purpose methods in order to reuse it in different applications: both MyWinForm and, let's say,  yawfs.sln (yet another windows form solution) so that I could create a reference to c.dll from both the solutions.  I guess that I should create a new class library *solution*  in order to reuse its classes. But, as far as I know, I cannot add a reference to a different solution: I can only add references to assemblies within the current solutions (different projects within the current solution) or to .Net assemblies. Should i use the navigation panel to select the a.dll assembly to add the reference  to it? Maybe there is a way to include an existing assembly to the current solution keeping it in sync with changes performed within the corresponding solution?  I do not understand.
2. What if I wish to extract b.dll from MyWinForm promoting it in order to serve to the very same purpose of c.dll? How I can promote it as a new solution?
3. Now let's say that I need to fork MyWinForm so that I'll have MyWinFormLeft.sln and  MyWinFormRight.sln; both will evolve in a different manner from a common shared code.  They will use (and share)  the very same a.dll and b.dll assemblies (same version) but the code in MyWinForm.cs  will start to change. What is the correct method to create a new solution from the existing one?

I know that my questions sound quite messy but the trouble come from the comparison I am trying to perform between  the joint VS and C# usage pattern against  the C compiler/linker  cycle I used time ago: compile the code to get your libraries  then link to them whatever application need them. Period.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: John, I was unaware of this. Thanks for informing.

Comment: Couldn't you create a generic class library that you can reference in your other projects? Or you can look into Service Oriented Architecture and use the internet to pass or invoke certain methods. You have a lot of choices here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as much a matter of personal preference as anything this.

You can have project in more than one solution. I personally think it's disaster waiting to happen, but it does have it's fans. I've seen people get into a serious mess dependency wise with this. If you come to refactor things and need to break some of the dependencies, you pull on one end of it and up with the entire parent solution in your lap. It needs some serious discipline, but if you break things up, you can't accidently shoot yourself in the foot like that.

You can just put everything in one solution, that has it's fans as well, and to be honset if I'm developing a number of libraries as the same time + prototye + unit tests it does save a lot of switching about.

The way I think you are saying you want to go and the way we tend to do it as well.

First you can add a reference to a dll that has been built from a project in an other solution
Just go into add reference, one of the tabs is Browse, pick the folder ,pick the dll.

Thing is you now have a build dependancy that's outside of your solution, no different to using a 3rd party dll.
So if you want to add another common function to common.dll, you have to switch solutions, add it, build it, switch solution (or have two copies of VS going)

After that it's just a question of how you make sure the dll you are referencing is the one you just built. That can be setting the build path to a common folder, or an after build event to copy it to where the the consuming project is expecting it. You could if you like pain manually copy it...

There's a lot of flex in this find a way that suits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

When faced with the need to share code between multiple solutions I tend to place that shared code into it's own solution and then package it up as a nuget (see [here for how](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package).)

The nuget can then be referenced by any solutions which need its facilities in a versioned and easy to synchronise / update way ([nugets can simply live in a local folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/nuget/hosting-packages/overview).)

Answer (score 1):

> I guess that I should create a new class library solution in order to reuse its classes

You guess correctly.

> I cannot add a reference to a different solution: I can only add references to assemblies within the current solutions

You can only add references to *projects* in the current solution.  You can add references to built *assemblies* that are the output of another solution.

> What if I wish to extract b.dll from MyWinForm

b.dll will be deployed independently of MyWinForm.exe - you do not need to "extract" it.

> Now let's say that I need to fork MyWinForm so that I'll have MyWinFormLeft.sln and MyWinFormRight.sln; ... What is the correct method to create a new solution from the existing one?

That depends on the severity of the differences between the two projects.  The common non-visual components could be classes in a shared class library.  The common visual components could be User Controls in the same or a separate class library.